# Active Directory Network Account does not have login keychain?

Tags: active-directory

I just bound my MacBook Pro to my Active Directory domain, so when I opened Mail and set up my email account, it asked if I'd like to remember in the keychain. Doing this on my other Mac on a local account, I said sure. It could not find nor create a login keychain using my network password. I have tried to make keychains, and they do not show up in Keychain Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed my copy of Mountain Lion on top of Lion, seems like everything works now. No issues, thanks anyway! Appreciate it :)

Comment: Beta or pre-release software, with a few exceptions, is off-topic for Ask Different.

Comment: What? All I did was mention that my developer copy of the 10.8 GM fixed my problem. I wasn't asking for help with 10.8 GM -_-

Comment: The problem is that we are geared for people that can't use GM or developer builds to solve their problems. Other sites do cover that ground, but we don't. I'll edit out the GM since it's reasonable to assume a normal MoLo install would also suffice to fix the issue you faced.

Answer (score 1):

In Directory Utility edit your Active Directory settings, under Advanced Options, check "Force local home directory on startup disk". I know this is disappointing as you probably want your documents folder to be your AD user folder, but it doesn't work.